# Docker container connection to host's Kafka throws : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-network

I have a nodejs app containerized as a linux container which uses the kafka-node library.

Kafka runs on the host machine which runs windows with:

- Zookeeper port : 2181
- Kafka broker port : 9092

I run the the nodejs container with the following command:

```
docker container run  --network host --name nm name:1.0
```

In order to connect with the host's kafka I am using the following command:

```
client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: "localhost:9092"});
```

But this throws :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9092
}
```

When I change the connect command to :

```
client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: "host.docker.internal:9092"});
```

I am getting :

```
TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms
    at new TimeoutError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/errors/TimeoutError.js:6:9)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:491:14)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  message: 'Request timed out after 30000ms'
}
```

Can someone advise what I am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

When switching to a linux host machine, the above localhost methodology runs just fine .

Comment: What is the host name / ip of the container that is running kafka, use that instead, as `--host` tells the container to defer network to the docker host.

Comment: Kafka is not dockerized but runs on the host's machine instead !

Comment: Ah, apologies, I assumed it was contained as well

Comment: On what platform are you running Docker (Linux/MacOS/Windows)?

Comment: @larsks I have edited. Hosts runs on windows, while the container is a linux container. On a Linux host it seems everything runs just fine ..

Comment: The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server. You can get docker host networking from official site: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ .   You can use the default network: bridge, which enable you to access application run on host by host ip/name: host port

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here, but I can solve

You must set the environment variable `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` with your domain `host.docker.internal:9092` in Kafka broker

My example:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    hostname: 'kafka-internal.io'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-internal.io
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

Now I can connect inside container using `kafka-internal.io:9092` :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but switching to a Linux host should make the first methodology (localhost:IP) run just fine .